# HAProxy path regexp based on map lookup

Tags: haproxy

I'm using HAProxy 1.8.14 on a server running Debian stretch.

I want to route requests to different backends for a certain set of domains but only for some specific paths. Since there's quite a few domains and varying paths allowed I think a solution using maps would be nice.

I've tried to use a map to lookup a backend based on hdr(host) with the condition that the path should match with a regular expression mapped to hdr(host). I've tried the following but I can't get it to work:

```
use_backend bk-%[hdr(host),lower,map_dom(/etc/haproxy/host_to_backend.map,bk_default)] if { path_reg %[hdr(host),lower,map_dom(/etc/haproxy/domain_path_whitelist.map)] }
```

Example of host_to_backend.map:

```
a.foo.org a
b.foo.org b
c.foo.org c
```

Example of domain_path_whitelist.map (regexps not tested):

```
a.foo.org ^/(yada|info)/.*$
b.foo.org ^.*$
c.foo.org ^/bar/.*$
```

To avoid the regexp complexities I've also tried a 'beg' alternative:

```
use_backend bk-%[hdr(host),lower,map_dom(/etc/haproxy/host_to_backend.map,bk_default)] if { path_beg %[hdr(host),lower,map_dom(/etc/haproxy/domain_path_whitelist.map)] }
```

...but no luck.

Is it possible to solve my specific problem using maps? If not, can you suggest an alternative solution?

Comment: The alternative solution would be haproxy acls https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#7 I can grab some examples of how to do this. Also, curious if it can be done with maps

Comment: Yup, I'd really prefer not to use acls however. Map files are so much easier to maintain, especially with hundreds of domains.

Comment: What you're doing with maps looks reasonable (not sure if the duplicative `bk` is intentional in the backend names). What about it isn't working?

Comment: The duplicate `bk` is just a typo. Well I just can't get the path to match with the regexp looked up from the map. The first part which looks up the backend name works well but I can't get the condition become true.

Comment: (I've fixed the typo now)

Comment: I'm going to test this in my local today and see if I can't help you out

Comment: Thank you @jmoney for trying to help

Comment: You're welcome! Wish I had a better answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the HAProxy community and [asked there too](https://discourse.haproxy.org/t/condition-with-path-reg-and-map-dom-with-regexps/3297). I'll probably go with the map_reg variant:

```
use_backend bk-%[base,lower,map_reg(/etc/haproxy/base_to_backend.map,bk_default)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done the way you are attempting because `log format variables` referenced `%[]` cannot be used in the acl match context. The `path_beg` acl is trying to literally match `%[hdr(host),lower,map_dom(/etc/haproxy/domain_path_whitelist.map)]`.

Also note, to match a regex on the path, you'd want to use [path_reg](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.8/configuration.html#7.3.6-path)

An alternative solution, is to use an acl without an attempt to map in a variable, for example:

```
use_backend bk-%[hdr(host),lower,map_dom(/etc/haproxy/host_to_backend.map,bk_default)] if { path_req ^/(yada|info)/.*$ }
```

Comment: Do you know of any other way to compare the path with a regexp loaded from a map file?

Comment: I'm reading the following in the documentation and can't help but wonder it may be part of a solution:

>>  The "-M" flag allows an ACL to use a map file. If this flag is set, the file is
parsed as two column file. The first column contains the patterns used by the
ACL, and the second column contain the samples. The sample can be used later by
a map. This can be useful in some rare cases where an ACL would just be used to
check for the existence of a pattern in a map before a mapping is applied. <<

but I'm not sure I fully understand the concept described. What do you think?

Comment: Hmm, yeah I missed that, it does look like it could work? My only concern is if it is going to expect all to match "The "-f" flag is followed by the name of a file from which all lines will be
read as individual values" i'm playing with it now

Comment: Have you figured out how to use it? the -M flag, looks like that in combo with -f

Comment: Yeah as I read it you use -f and then -M to use the file as a map file but I don't understand how to apply "The first column contains the patterns used by the
ACL, and the second column contain the samples. The sample can be used later by a map." So, no, I haven't figured it out yet :(